# Parsing of CSV to Bean using Open CSV

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have following text in CSV:

`# Title: Chilling# Generated: 982398738249 (2012-01-10 04:10:21) # User name;User ID;User description;Total Space (MB); ram_prasad;MN012;ayodh rastar;11214;shyam_prasad;MN013;dwark rastar;4114;`

I am using Open CSV to parse:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is); 
CSVReader csv = new CSVReader(reader,',');
CsvToBean<FromBackup> csvb = new CsvToBean<FromBackup>();

Map<String, String> columnMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
columnMapping.put("User name ","userName"); //1st is column recieved in CSV and second is bean name private String userName;
columnMapping.put("User ID","userID");
columnMapping.put("User description","userDescription");
columnMapping.put("Total Space (MB)","totalSpaceHosted");
HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<FromBackup> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<FromBackup>();

strategy.setType(FromBackup.class);

strategy.setColumnMapping(columnMapping);

List<FromBackup> list = csvb.parse(strategy, csv);

System.out.println(""+list);

FromBackupfnb = (FromBackup)list.get(0);

System.out.println("username "+fnb.getUserName());
```

It is giving Null. i.e fnb.getUsername gives NULL as output. 
Could you please help in finding whether i am doing correct. I am receiving CSV text from a web link. Tried to found on web but unable to succeed.

**An Update**

Now i did following:

```
CSVReader csv = new CSVReader(reader,','); //Comma instead of semi colon

ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<FromBackup> strategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<FromBackup>(); strategy.setType(FromBackup.class); 
strategy.setColumnMapping(new String [] { "userName", "User ID", "userDescription","totalSpaceHosted" });
```

Result: Got CSV line in first field i.e username = ram_prasad;MN012;ayodh rastar;11214 but UserID, UserDescription, TotalSpaceHosted is still NULL.

When i put semi colon it gives parsing error

Comment: Is your CSV is valid in excel?

Comment: _It is giving Null_ Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: CSV is received as a text. In excel it is showing whole CSV in single column. Null elaborated above

Comment: You state "csv" but the data uses semicolon and your code uses comma.  Oh and pls learn the 4-space indent format so we can read your code.

Comment: Unable to understand 3 space indent. Tried it for 15 minutes but stack overflow was not accepting :( .

Comment: As i mentioned at last that i have used Semicolon too but in Vein CSVReader(reader,';'); <-